# ClassNotFoundException is thrown when trying to grab groovy-ssh plugin with Grape

Tags: groovy, ssh

When I simply grab groovy-ssh plugin with Grape, an exception is thrown. I use the code from here: https://github.com/int128/groovy-ssh

```
@Grab('org.hidetake:groovy-ssh:1.5.0')
@Grab('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2')
def ssh = org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.Ssh.newService()
println "Test"

BUG! exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit 'delete.groovy' # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
```

Anyone seen this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of a [transitive dependency on groovy-all](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7613) in groovy-ssh

Fix it with:

```
@Grab('org.hidetake:groovy-ssh:1.4.0')
@GrabExclude('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all')
@Grab('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2')
def ssh = org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.Ssh.newService()
println "Test"
```